# How can I find repeated words in a vector of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a `std::vector<string>` where each element is a word. I want to print the vector *without* repeated words!

I searched a lot on the web and I found lots of material, but I can't and I don't want to use hash maps, iterators and "advanced" (to me) stuff. I can only use plain string comparison `==` as I am still a beginner.

So, let `my_vec` a `std::vector<std::string>` initialized from std input. My idea was to read all the vector and erase any repeated word once I found it:

```
  for(int i=0;i<my_vec.size();++i){
    for (int j=i+1;j<my_vec.size();++j){
      if(my_vec[i]==my_vec[j]){
        my_vec.erase(my_vec.begin()+j); //remove the component from the vector
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to test for `std::vector<std::string> my_vec{"hey","how","are","you","fine","and","you","fine"}`

and indeed I found

> hey how are you fine and

so it seems to be right, but for instance if I write the simple vector `std::vector<std::string> my_vec{"hello","hello","hello","hello","hello"}`

I obtain

> hello hello

The problem is that at every call to `erase` the dimension gets smaller and so I lose information. How can I do that?

Comment: Ironically, `std::vector::erase` solves this problem by returning a new iterator. You can emulate this by counteracting the `++j`.

Comment: You really should at least use iterators, as it will literally solve your problem in doing so, whilst promoting in the gentlest way possible something you should be embracing long-term to begin with (i.e. iterators; the standard library literally lives and dies by them).

Comment: would it be ok if the order of the words is changed? Or do you need them to be printed in the order they are stored in the vector?

Comment: The simpler solution is to create a new duplicate-free vector.

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes it's okay if the order of the words is changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimalist approach to your existing code. The auto-increment of `j` is what is ultimately breaking your algorithm. Don't do that. Instead, only increment it when you do NOT remove an element.

I.e.

```
for (int i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < my_vec.size(); ) {  // NOTE: no ++j
        if (my_vec[i] == my_vec[j]) {
            my_vec.erase(my_vec.begin() + j);
        }
        else ++j; // NOTE: moved to else-clause
    }
}
```

That is literally it.

Comment: many thanks for your answer, it's exactly what I was looking for. Btw, I'm trying to keep track of the number of repetitions: I defined a dynamic array `repts` of length my_vec.size() and I do `repts[i]++` inside the `if`. However, I don't get the correct result. What's the problem? @WhozCraig

Comment: @Vefhug hard saying without actually seeing how you're doing it. Frankly, I'd use an `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` for that, but if you're seriously married to the idea of side-by-side vectors you could [do it like this](https://ideone.com/NNthQO)

Comment: I'm trying to use now `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`, but I really can't understand how to do it because I never used it. How would you accomplish the task using it?

Comment: @Vefhug Funny you should ask. [See example here](https://ideone.com/xZNTmH). Key to that approach is the value-initialization of a new mapped-to element in the map; it's zero. so `++m[*it]` will be `1` only on the first insertion (and thus we skip erasure from the vector). Otherwise, it will be > 1 and we (a) maintain that updated count in the map, and (b) know we need to erase that instance from the vector. Honestly you don't even need the vector unless you want the original vector order kept (which you do).

Comment: I didn't know that way, thanks. @WhozCraig Could you confirm that this is much slower than the approach with `std::vector`? I read from a huge `.txt` file and the time with this last approach is abou two times the old one.

Comment: @Vefhug Performance is very much data-set dependent. If you had a million unique strings in a file of two-million strings, I guarantee the unordered map solution will perform far better the linear search methodology, especially if you optimize out reading the entire file into the vector and instead load the vector only with unique strings based on the map as you read the file. The nested loop *may* perform better with very few unique instances in a similar file of two-million total strings.

Comment: @Vefhug [See this sample](https://pastebin.com/RrVLe8Mz). It uses three different methodologies for detecting duplicates while maintaining encounter-order. The first is an optimized linear probe (i.e. your nested loop scan), the second an ordered map, and the last an unordered map (i.e. a hash table). The results are pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)?

You can use it as easy as:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> v{ "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello" };
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
```

**N.B.** Elements need to be sorted because `std::unique` works only for consecutive duplicates.

In case you don't want to change the content of the `std::vector`, but only have stable output, I recommend other answers.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that it needs to be sorted.

Comment: as I understood the question the output should be stable, ie sorting inst an option (unless you restore the original order afterwards)

Comment: @idclev463035818 ah, i didn't get that from the question but most probably you are right

Comment: might be my interpretation only. Checked the question again and OP doesn't mention it explicitly

Comment: @idclev463035818 I will reference your answer in my answer then

Comment: @NutCracker As idclev pointed out, I'm just interested in printing with no repetition, ignoring sorting! Btw, I didn't know std::unique, thanks :)

Comment: turns out that I was wrong. Actually I would prefer if you don't reference my answer, because there are better ones (including this one)

Answer (score 2):

**You can store the element element index to erase and then eliminate it at the end.
Or repeat the cycle until no erase are performed.**

**First code Example:**

```
std::vector<int> index_to_erase();

for(int i=0;i<my_vec.size();++i){
    for (int j=i+1;j<my_vec.size();++j){
      if(my_vec[i]==my_vec[j]){
        index_to_erase.push_back(j);
        
      }
    }
  }
//starting the cycle from the last element to the vector of index, in this 
//way the vector of element remains equal for the first n elements
for (int i = index_to_erase.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
   my_vec.erase(my_vec.begin()+index_to_erase[i]); //remove the component from the vector
}
```

**Second code Example:**

```
bool Erase = true;
while(Erase){
  Erase = false;
  for(int i=0;i<my_vec.size();++i){
    for (int j=i+1;j<my_vec.size();++j){
      if(my_vec[i]==my_vec[j]){
        my_vec.erase(my_vec.begin()+j); //remove the component from the vector
        Erase = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it works because i start remove elements from the last index, this ensure that the first n element does not change their index

Comment: thats clever, maybe so clever that it needs a comment or a little explanation

Comment: The approach in the **first code** is another way I tried, but I stopped because I wasn't able to delete just the values corresponding to a set of integers, but I really like your way to start from the bottom @ZigRazor

Comment: @Vefhug the cycle over the `index_to_erase` is the piece of code that erase the element from your vector.

Comment: @ZigRazor yes I realized it, I was just saying it was where I stucked before :) Now it's perfectly clear

Comment: perfect, sorry for my misunderstood. Remember to vote up if usefull!

Answer (score 0):

Erasing elements from a container inside a loop is a little tricky, because after erasing element at index `i` the next element (in the next iteration) is not at index `i+1` but at index `i`.

Read about the erase-remove-idiom for the idomatic way to erase elements. However, if you just want to print on the screen there is a much simpler way to fix your code:

```
for(int i=0; i<my_vec.size(); ++i){
   bool unique = true;
   for (int j=0; j<i; ++j){
       if(my_vec[i]==my_vec[j]) {
           unique = false;
           break; 
       }
       if (unique) std::cout << my_vec[i];
   }
}
```

Instead of checking for elements after the current one you should compare to elements before. Otherwise "bar x bar y bar" will result in "x x bar" when I suppose it should be "bar x y".

Last but not least, consider that using the traditional loops with indices is the complicated way, while using iterators or a range-based loop is much simpler. Don't be afraid of new stuff, on the long run it will be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the combination of `sort` and `unique` as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec{"hey","how","are","you","fine","and","you","fine"};
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase(unique(vec.begin(), vec.end() ), vec.end());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i ++) {
        std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you sort the vector ? I'm missing this point

Comment: @Vefhug without the sort `std::unique` won't work as desired.

Comment: Okay, now I see: `std::unique` works only for consecutive duplicates